# Android Convert Ruby on Rails Timestamp to Date Time

Tags: java, android, timestamp

I am building an Android App, Fetching Data from API that is build in Ruby On Rails Framework.
Here is my timestamp string
2000-01-01T12:00:00.000Z

I need to convert it to Readable date and time format i.e "Saturday January 1st, 2000 12:00 am"

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
public static String convertDate(String oldDateString){
    String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZZZZ";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // handle exception here !
    }

    String newFormatString = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' HH:mm a";

    SimpleDateFormat newFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(newFormatString);



    String newDateString = newFormatter.format(date);

    return newDateString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I tried @real19 answer but it gave me errors.
I came with that then :

```
  public static String convertDate(String oldDateString){
    String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // handle exception here !
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String newFormatString = "EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' HH:mm a";

    SimpleDateFormat newFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(newFormatString);

    String newDateString = newFormatter.format(date);

    return newDateString;
}
```

Formatting gave me `jeudi décembre 22, 2016 at 16:42 PM` but you can adjust your DateFormat